# How to ignore rows with zero value in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to show the results only if the total price is more than 0.

This is my DB table:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  id  |     name       |   phone    |   price   | status |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |      John      | 0701111111 |    300    |   1    |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  2   |      Lucy      | 0702222222 |    500    |   1    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|  3   |      Adam      | 0703333333 |    700    |   0    |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  4   |      Lucy      | 0702222222 |   -500    |   -1   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  5   |      John      | 0701111111 |    450    |   1    |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  6   |      Mike      | 0704444444 |    150    |   1    |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm trying to show only the total price of each paying person by distinct phone and status (1 = paid, -1 = refund, 0 = not payed)

Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT(presents_test.phone) AS uniquePhone,
(SELECT MIN(name) FROM presents_test WHERE phone = uniquePhone AND status != 0) AS name,
(SELECT SUM(price) FROM presents_test WHERE phone = uniquePhone AND status != 0) AS totalPrice
FROM presents_test
WHERE status != 0
```

The result is:

```
-----------------------------------
| uniquePhone | name | totalPrice |
-----------------------------------
| 0701111111  | John |    750     |
-----------------------------------
| 0702222222  | Lucy |     0      |
-----------------------------------
| 0704444444  | Mike |    150     |
-----------------------------------
```

I just need to ignore the Lucy row because it's 0 price.

I've tried to add `AND totalPrice > 0` to WHERE clause but it gets an error of unknown column.

What can i do to solve this?

Comment: Skip the subqueries, simply do a GROUP BY. And use HAVING to avoid Lucy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by the phone number. When you group then aggregation functions like `SUM` apply to each group. And `HAVING` is the `WHERE` clause for grouped data

```
SELECT phone AS uniquePhone,
       MIN(name) AS name,
       SUM(price) AS totalPrice
FROM presents_test
WHERE status <> 0
GROUP BY phone
HAVING SUM(price) > 0
```